# Value change event is not firing in jquery

Tags: jquery

My code:

```
 $('#CustomerEmail').on("keyup change paste autocompletechange", function () {

        var url = $('#webroot').text() + 'orders/' + 'loadCustomer';
        var field = $(this).val();
        var data = 'email=' + field;// +'&calibri=' + 'nolibri';
        getCustomer(url, data);


    });
```

This code works fine when I type email for #CustomerEmail character by character and it works fine even if I past the email. But when it is suggested in dropdown box (recent email lists are suggested) as like:
[image]

When I type 's' sattar.kuet@gmail.com is suggested. I mouse over this value and click then email input field is filled up by: sattar.kuet@gmail.com

But the

```
$('#CustomerEmail').on("keyup change paste autocompletechange", function () {
```

is not triggering. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to simply use `.on("input", function () {`

Comment: Try listening for the `input` event?

Comment: I just tried. And it works. Thanks @Roko C. Buljan for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested to trigger an event once an *editable action* element **changes it's value**:

```
.on("input", function () {
```

is the simplest you could get for all kind of different "events" types, in one.